# Worksheet_Calculate on multiple ranges

Tags: vba, excel

I have the current code calculating a single cell's value then calling a module if it's value exceeds another value.

How can I make it check multiple ranges of cells eg B5:E5, B8:M8 and call the module if any of the cells in the range exceed the value.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
If Range("B5") > 4 Then
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.Run "Mail_small_Text_Outlook"
Application.EnableEvents = True
End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are trying?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
    Dim aRng As Range, bRng As Range
    Dim aCell As Range

    Set aRng = Range("B5:E5")
    Set bRng = Range("B8:M8")

    For Each aCell In aRng
        If aCell.Value > 4 Then
            '
            Application.Run "Mail_small_Text_Outlook"
            '
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Next

    For Each aCell In bRng
        If aCell.Value > 4 Then
            '
            Application.Run "Mail_small_Text_Outlook"
            '
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

or something like this?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
    Dim aRng As Range, bRng As Range
    Dim aCell As Range, uRng As Range

    Set aRng = Range("B5:E5")
    Set bRng = Range("B8:M8")
    Set uRng = Union(aRng, bRng)

    For Each aCell In uRng
        If aCell.Value > 4 Then
            '
            Application.Run "Mail_small_Text_Outlook"
            '
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: The first example was what I was after. Thank you!

Comment: Hi Siddarth, this works fine however it calculates the entire worksheet each time data is entered, even if the new data entered is out of the range the formula is calculating and sends an email each time. Is there a way to somehow dismiss the alert once an email has been sent so that it doesn't send mail each time data is entered?

Comment: Yes, you can use the Intersect Method. Will the data be manually entered in those two ranges?

Comment: the ranges specified are actually pulled by formula which collects data from other sheets in the same workbook. However when a user makes a change on any cell, even out of the ranges, the worksheetcalculate is triggered and the email is send.