# Call a function when only a specific Excel cell changes on Formula Recalculation

Tags: vba, excel

As far as i know, `Worksheet_Calculate` is called when the value of any cell in a worksheet changes on Formula recalculation.

Is there a way so that i need a function to be called only when a specific cell changes on Formula Recalculation

Comment: I think you'd need to track the current value and then within each Worksheet_Calculate event you'd check whether it had changed...

Comment: How does the specific cell value change? Is it a formula, linked to an external workbook, web query etc?

Comment: Agree with Tim here. See this example. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11754047/worksheet-calculate-on-multiple-ranges In this example am using a hardcoded value. you can pick up that value in the `Workbook_Open()` event and store it in a public variable and then from there constantly track it

Comment: Is there a reason you cannot use a user-defined worksheet function (UDF)?

Comment: I ended up using a UDF. But then needed to work inside the Constraint that a UDF cant modify the value of any other Cells

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me see if I interpret your question correctly. You want to know if it is possible to only kickoff a macro if a particular cell (or group of cells) is changed.

The answer is Yes. To tweak Ed's code a little.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(byval target as range)

    If Not Intersect(target.address, Range("YourCells")) is Nothing Then 
       MyMacro()
    End If

End Sub
```

I think your use of "function" is throwing people off. That's why Ed's answer is so elaborate.

Ok. It is possible that you stated your question correctly and you just want to gain efficiency. In that case, Ed's answer solves your immediate problem, but will cause the spreadsheet NOT to calculate automatically when you change other cells.

Comment: I think you got me Right, ROb.
I had lots of Cells that to be Recalculated by a Sub  when a Cell changed.
I found that recalculation of each of this cells is again itself calling Worsheet_Calculate

Comment: [verging on -1]...marked as correct but this errors for me - `Intersect` defintely requires an additional parameter

Comment: It's supposed to be a comma and not =.

Comment: I could only get this working by changing `target.address` to `Range(target.address)`

Answer (score 2):

To make something happen when a specific cell is changed, you need to embed the relevant selection change event within the file `Worksheet_Change(byval target as Range)`. We can re-calculate a worksheet when your cell changes as follows:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(byval target as range)

    If target.address = Range("YourCell").Address Then Application.Calculate

End Sub
```

Now what you want to do is switch off calculations the rest of the time. If you only want to switch off calculations on the single sheet (and not your whole file), you will need to turn calculations off when it is activated, and on when deactivated e.g.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Deactivate

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

End Sub
```

Of course, your requirements to re-calculate may be considerably more complex than the example above. Firstly, you may open the file whilst on the sheet in question in which case you should use the Workbook_Open event to detect your sheet, and set calculations accordingly

Then you may have several cells that may require some sort of calculation. Presumably the reason you want to switch off calculations is that the file is running too slowly. If so, and you are identifying all the input cells, you could enter the outputs using code. One method would be to enter the formulas using this guide to [entering formulas in Excel Visual Basic](http://www.excel4business.com/videos/excel-formulas-with-vba.php). You could then replace the formula with the calculated value e.g. `Range("YourCell") = Range("YourCell").Value`...so stopping the number of formulas in the sheet constantly growing