# Macro for Advanced Filter not working automatically

Tags: excel, vba

I currently have a macro to autofilter my data. I can't get it to run automatically when a cell changes. I want the macro to run whenever the value in a cell change. Would be grateful for any kind of help. I am wondering if the problem lies with which worksheet i'm placing my code in.

My code is as follows.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim KeyCells As Range

    ' The variable KeyCells contains the cells that will
    ' cause an alert when they are changed. In this case, 
    ' Cell B2 will be changed when a value is selected on
    ' another worksheet.
    Set KeyCells = Range("B1:B2")

    If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Range(Target.Address)) _
       Is Nothing Then

    ' Perform advanced filter on data
    ' Place your code here.
     Range("B4:H976").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterInPlace, CriteriaRange:= _
        Range("SalesByLocation!Criteria"), Unique:=False

End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tried to debug it? Set a breakpoint at `Set KeyCells = Range("B1:B2")` and see if gets hit.

Comment: Hi there, what do you mean by setting a breakpoint?

Comment: To set a breakpoint, place the cursor in the line `Set KeyCells = ...` and press F9. When the code gets executed, i.e. the event fires, VBA will stop the execution - and you can step through the code with F8 to see what's happening. Give it a try and let use know how it went. PS: Please use @username in any comment so please will get notified by your response!

Comment: +1 interesting problem

Comment: Did any of the answers help? Some feedback - or upping some of the answers - or even marking one as the answer is the usual protocol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem! I ended up separating the codes into different forms and then calling the advanced filter macro. I guess there was a little problem with my codes in front. Changed it to something like this.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Intersect(Target, Range("C4")) Is Nothing Then
        Exit Sub
    Else
        Call Sheet4.AFilter
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO!

You need to place your code in the worksheet module on which you will apply the changes. I.e. don't place it in any module, but double click the SheetX of your project (X being the number of the sheet).

Looking at your code, you probably should also insert

```
Application.EnableEvents = False
```

after the `IF` clause and then

```
Application.EnableEvents = True
```

before `End If`. Else the event code might trigger the event again, resulting in an actual stack overflow.

Comment: I placed it in the worksheet module like you said and inserted both the statement into my code but it still doesn't run the macro when the value gets changed.

Comment: ...also though I'd be tempted to use the Immediate Window to run this line of code `Application.EnableEvents = True` just to make sure events are on

Answer (score 0):

Works fine for me.

Try opening the Immediate Window (Ctrl+G) and type the following and then hit enter:

```
 Application.EnableEvents = True
```

Now see if the code works?
This will ensure that the application is listening out for events to fire.

As a test I've been using the following and the message box appears fine:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim KeyCells As Range
    Set KeyCells = Range("B1:B2")

    If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Range(Target.Address)) Is Nothing Then

            ' Perform advanced filter on data
            ' Place your code here.
            MsgBox "Hello Event"

    End If

End Sub
```

How are the values in B1:B2 changed? - via a formula that is in the cells? Or does a user go into the cell, change the value, and then press enter? ...the second option is what has been implemented.

---

**Edit**

I think you'll need to explore the `worksheet_calculate` event

[REFERENCE TO OTHER SO ARTICLE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11754047/worksheet-calculate-on-multiple-ranges)

---

**Further Edit**

You might be better creating an event procedure for the change event of the combo-box that is feeding the values in `B1:B2`. This closed question is actually a good starting point as it has quite a few links to other questions:

[REFERENCE TO OTHER SO ARTICLE ABOUT COMBOBOX EVENTS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13842253/excel-2010-vba-is-it-possible-to-create-a-change-event-on-all-the-comboboxes-on)

Comment: i tried using your codes as a test and the msgbox does not appear. is it due to how the values in B2 are changed? since its via a formula that takes in what the user selects from a dropdown list on another worksheet?

Comment: try just entering a number in the cell with your keyboard(you can always copy the formula back in) and after entering the number press enter

Comment: i believe its a problem with the trigger point of the worksheet. I'm selecting from a dropdown list on worksheet1 and the advanced filter takes place on worksheet2. i think that is why the first part of the code does not run.