# How to hide a row if a cell is input Excel

Tags: excel, vba

Is it possible to hide a row if a cell has a particular value input?

ie Cell B2 has a value of 1, then hide row B4 and then if B2 = 0 then row is shown?

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20986436/hiding-rows-in-excel-based-on-words-in-a-cell?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
If Range("A1") = "blabla" Then
    Range("A1").EntireRow.Hidden = True
Else
    Range("A1").EntireRow.Hidden = False
End If
```